# Auto reply in Gmail, when using Gmail for several domains/addresses

Tags: gmail, automation

I'm using the "**Send mail as**" (Use Gmail to send from your other email addresses) feature to send from my unique Gmail account interface, all the mails for:

- myname@gmail.com
- contact@example1.com
- contact@example2.com

I would like to configure an auto-response, but *specific to each domain*, like:

> Thank you for contacting us. We will answer you as soon as possible, with a maximum delay of 24 hours. Kind regards -- Tech support of *example1.com*.

However, Gmail's *Settings > General* only offers a general **Out of Office AutoReply**:

[image]

**Question: how to configure an auto-reply feature in Gmail specific to each email address that I'm using Gmail with?** (if not possible inside Gmail, is there a free/easy-to-use external tool?)

---

Note: [this workaround](https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-send-canned-replies-automatically-in-gmail-1172080) doesn't work because all the emails are sent from `myname+canned.response@gmail.com`.

Comment: Interesting : https://www.pygaze.org/2015/06/selective-gmail-autoreply/